# Cant login facebook in android "Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.katana.provider.AttributionIdProvider"

Tags: android, facebook, api, single-sign-on

I am a beginner of android programming. I am trying to use facebook SSO, therefore I follow the instruction of facebook developers and write a simple testing code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private Facebook facebook = new Facebook("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
/** Called when the activity is first created. */   

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        //@Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            facebook.authorize( MainActivity.this, new DialogListener(){
                @Override
                public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                }
                @Override
                public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                }
                @Override
                public void onError(DialogError e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                }
                @Override
                public void onCancel() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                }
             });
        }
    }); 

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

The first time I finish the coding it works. The dialog pop out and I can input my email and password. However, the same cant work after the first time. I checked the LogCat and find out the error:

```
10-17 17:10:07.227: E/ActivityThread(638): Failed to find provider info for       
com.facebook.katana.provider.AttributionIdProvider
```

I have tried many time and what I see is the dialog pop out but close immediately. I have checked for solution and I am sure that the Key Hash matched. Can anyone tell me why? Thanks a lot.

Sorry for my stupid question. I have found that in the LogCat there is a "D/Facebook-authorize(638): Login Success! access_token=...... expires=.....", So I suggest the codes word? however why I dont need to login again even I close my emulator, reboot my computer? How can I switch to other facebook account if I want? Thx a lot.

Comment: Perhaps you should fill in the auto-generated callback stubs (particularly `onFacebookERror` and `onError`) to log any feedback returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the login is success. But here's are some suggestion.
If you want to see the dialog page and want to re-enter the user name and password, try to clear the caches of yours apps first before running it again.