# Unable to login to Facebook using both emulator and phone

Tags: android, android-emulator, facebook-android-sdk

I'm having trouble logging into Facebook using both the Emulator and my phone.
The phone does give me Facebook's login screen but after I punch in my username and password, the button image doesnt change + I get the error message "Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.katana.provider.AttributionIdProvider".
When trying to login from my phone, the FB login page opens for about 2 seconds and immediately closes back to my layout.

What's wrong?

```
package com.test.facebookapp;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.facebook.android.DialogError;
import com.facebook.android.Facebook;
import com.facebook.android.Facebook.DialogListener;
import com.facebook.android.FacebookError;

public class StartingPlace extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    Facebook fb;
    ImageView pic,button;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        String APP_ID = getString(R.string.APP_ID);
        button = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.login);
        pic = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.picture_pic);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);
        fb = new Facebook(APP_ID);
        updateButtonImage();

    } 
    private void updateButtonImage() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (fb.isSessionValid()){
            button.setImageResource(R.drawable.logout_button);
        }
        else{
            button.setImageResource(R.drawable.login_button);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (fb.isSessionValid()){
            //button will close session - logout
            try {
                fb.logout(getApplicationContext());
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            updateButtonImage();
        }
        else{
            //login to facebook
            fb.authorize(StartingPlace.this, new DialogListener() {

                @Override
                public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Toast.makeText(StartingPlace.this, "fbError", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(DialogError e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Toast.makeText(StartingPlace.this, "DialogError", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    updateButtonImage();
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancel() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Toast.makeText(StartingPlace.this, "onCancel", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

        }
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }




}




<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.test.facebookapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.test.facebookapp.StartingPlace"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Thanks!

Comment: can you specify logcat errors?

Comment: Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.katana.provider.AttributionIdProvider

I get that on the Emulator. Nothing much on the phone.

Comment: please check related [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12939979/cant-login-facebook-in-android-failed-to-find-provider-info-for-com-facebook-ka)

Comment: Thanks for the link!
How can I tell if my session has successfully logged in though? I cant see anything in Logcat...

Answer (score 2):

you must export a signed apk and install it to the mobile.

fb dos not work on debugging unless you use a debug fb Key

Comment: Does that mean there's no way to test my app out?

Comment: you can. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5170544/android-facebook-single-sign-on-multiple-key-hashes-possible AND https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/#sig

Answer (score 0):

Well, it turns out something was messed up with my Facebook settings.
I deleted my app, recreated it with more care and it now logs in and out as it should. :)
Thank you guys a bunch though. Those tips should come in handy.